# Creating webapp similar to Opportunity Atlas with ArcGIS Online and Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

If you have not looked at it yet, the [Opportunity Atlas](https://www.opportunityatlas.org/) provides analysis on 'Which neighborhoods in America offer children the best chance to rise out of poverty?'

I have been trying to create something similar with ArcGIS Online Web AppBuilder but I am unable to figure out how to create a gis web app that can take inputs similar to Opportunity Atlas and update the map accordingly.

Concretely, the opportunity atlas takes input from users and draw visualizations on the map accordingly by processing the data. The user gives an input, say a county, and the associated census results, and the map lays it out. This will require processing at the database end. However, the webapp builder can only display layers that have already been created. Essentially, I want to create and display layers based on user inputs.

Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I've removed your second question that sought alternative software recommendations.  For that there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.  Where did you get stuck trying to do this using ArcGIS Online and the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder?

Comment: @PolyGeo, the opportunity atlas takes input from users and draw visualizations on the map accordingly by processing the data. The user gives an input, say a county, and the associated census results, and the map lays it out. This will require processing at the database end.

Comment: I can create individual layers in the web map but I cannot create layers in real time based on user data.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: At it's simplest form, I would say this is just making use of custom filters. So try setting up a map with the data (needs to be a polygon layer containing all info) and set up the filter widget. The filters can work together in this same fashion.